# root.delay.output.output: Internal error: agent 1080 is already pending as 'ready' on some other port: root.delay.output.out

Tags: anylogic

I am not sure how to describe the issue here but when in run the simulation i am getting 2 types of errors. sometimes error 1 pops up and sometimes error 2 pops up. i am not sure why this is occurring. i have attached the images.

Please help me with this issue

[error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIa8A.png)

[error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n869f.png)

[logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QaDC.png)

[logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4R9xh.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accidentally trying to have the same agent in 2 flowchart blocks at the same time. This is not allowed.

How to fix this? Hard to say for your specific case.

You need to start building models in a way that you catch these problems directly, i.e.:

1. build extremely simple flow
2. test test test
3. add a TINY feature
4. test test test
5. rinse and repeat

this way, you would know instantly which tiny change caused your error and could rectify immediately.

Now, you are stuck with a huge flow chart and you will have to peel back and simplify until it works. Then, you find your root cause.